# How to set up a SOCKSport?

Tags: help, socks, torsocks

I'd like to know how to set up a SOCKSport on Tor Windows and how to create a SOCKS policy.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you describe what you want to achieve by setting a `SOCKSPort`? In general you can just edit your `torrc` and add something like `SocksPort 12345`.

Comment: I'm trying to bypass captcha on Omegle to pulse my chatroom again. Can I show you what I've typed in the torrc file?

Comment: You can either edit your question and insert it or use an Etherpad like https://pad.systemli.org/ to paste it there. However I don't see how a SocksPort can help with circumventing CAPTCHAs. Could you exaplin it a bit?